# How to update and insert in T-SQL in one query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a database that needs from time to time an update.
It may also happens that there are new data while the update runs.

In MySQL there is a option

```
INSERT INTO IGNORE
```

I can't find something like this in T-SQL.
No Problem to update ID 1-4 but then there is a new record for ID 5.
The UPDATE query don't work here.
And when I try to INSERT all data again I get a DUPLICATE KEY error.

**Additional Infos:**
I've forgotten to say that my data come from external sources. I call an API to get data from it. From there I have to insert these data into my database.

I have to admit that I don't understand MERGE. So my solution for now is to use TRUNCATE first and then insert all data again.
Not the best solution but MERGE works, so far I understand it, with two tables. But I have only one table. And to create a table temporarly to use MERGE and later drop that table is in my eyes a bit to much for my little table with 200 records in it.

Comment: The answer is the `merge` statement:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `MERGE` keyword. Basically, you need to specify the column(s) on which to join the source of data with target table, and depending on whether it is matching (existing record) or not matching (new record), you run an `UPDATE` or `INSERT`.

Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx

Comment: Ok, thank you. 
But will this work when I won't join tables?
My data will come from external sources e.g. the web.

Comment: I guess you could store that data in a DataTable if you are using C#, and then use normal SQL-related methods to make it work. Example here: http://www.jarloo.com/c-bulk-upsert-to-sql-server-tutorial/

Comment: Ok, too bad.
MERGE seems only to work with TABLES and not with variables or string.

Comment: Can you edit your question to make your requirement clearer then? As it stands, what readers will understand from your question doesn't imply what you say in your above comment.

Answer (score 0):

Is a stored procedure an option?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.Testing (@ID int, @Field1 varchar(20))
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE tblTesting
    SET Field1 = @Field1
    WHERE ID = @ID

    IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
        INSERT INTO tblTesting (ID, Field1) SELECT @ID, @Field1
END
```